# High disk IO in Kubernetes nodes

Tags: java, kubernetes, spinnaker

Deployed 3 node K8s cluster on CentOS 7 VMs(vsphear) with `kubeadm`.

```
Master - 4GB    
Minion1 - 6GB RAM
Minion2 - 6GB RAM
K8s Version - v1.11.2
```

Before starting kubelet daemon on each node, I did `swapoff -a` to disable swap memory which is recommended for K8s

Deployed [Spinnaker](https://www.spinnaker.io/) on K8s cluster and I see all spinnaker components are spring boot java applications.

I noticed that after some time, I'm losing ssh connection(able to ping) and nodes become `NotReady` state. After force restart of nodes, I started `kubelet`(after `swapoff -a`) while looking I/O states, `iotop`. Then I saw that java application doing lot of Disk Reads but not much CPU and memory. Also noticed that, sometimes nodes alive for long times(Hours). Verified same scenario few times in vsphear UI graph(sudden increase of disk reads).

Now my question is, too many disk reads/IO because of `swapoff -a`? or java application doesn't like disabling swap memory?
I see some similar issue in [k8s github repo](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/47928).

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried not disabling swap on your configuration?

Comment: `Kubelet` wont start, if I enable swap. `failed to run Kubelet: Running with swap on is not supported, please disable swap! or set --fail-swap-on flag to false. /proc/swaps contained: [Filename Type Size  Used Priority /dev/dm-1 partition 4063228 0 -1]`

Comment: Try to set `--fail-swap-on` flag to `false`. That way we can rule out that disabling swap is the culprit. And that would mean either a memory leak or insufficient memory, probably.

Comment: I forgot, I already mentioned the flag in `/etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d/10-kubeadm.conf`...`Environment="KUBELET_EXTRA_ARGS=--fail-swap-on=false"`. Anyway, in k8s upgrade version post(https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/kubeadm/kubeadm-upgrade-1-11/), mentioned `Swap must be disabled. The cluster should use a static control plane and etcd pods.`

Comment: That's for upgrade process, not for running applications

Comment: If you had `KUBELET_EXTRA_ARGS=--fail-swap-on=false` then the error `failed to run Kubelet: Running with swap on is not supported, please disable swap! or set --fail-swap-on flag to false.` would not happen. You need to research better if you want us to be able to help.

Comment: Swap is used to temporary unload pages from RAM to disk drive to free some RAM space for more important process. When you turn off swap you should have enough RAM for all your running processes. Could you check what is the memory usage on your nodes?

Comment: @VAS Right now I removed the setup. But I saw the memory usage looks fine.